# Creating Chrome popup with a C++ program

Tags: google-chrome, popup

**Problem context:**

I have a C++ program and a web presence. Currently the way things are working I have made a control panel with javascript and html. And it send commands via an unimportant communication medium to control things or get information from the C++ program.

Now, when the C++ program launches, I'm making it run a

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", addressBuffer," --new-window", NULL, SW_NORMAL);
```

This is a way of launching the default browser with the given address. The addressBuffer in this case points to an intermediate HTML file that quickly turns around and uses the

```
window.open()
```

in Javascript to open the final popup, then closes itself.

The result is the user now has the popup control panel that I want them to have but the user's main browser window also gets given focus, un-minimized, and placed on a different tab than the one they had selected. (Basically pops up out of nowhere and selects a another tab)

**Problem:**

I'm looking for a way to launch a Chrome popup, without disturbing a previously open browser window. Any ideas or solutions would be very helpful.

Lastly, it's worth noting that the " --new-window" from the code above doesn't actually open a new window like you would expect. In this case it's actually doing nothing... If it did work, none of this would really be an issue.

I know this is wordy so thanks in advance for you time!

-Michael

Comment: Alright, I didn't know enough about this place to know that I needed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I came up with a solution.

Something about how ShellExecute processes it's commands was preventing the command line args to be passed in correctly.

My work-around includes grabbing the path to Chrome from the registry,
HKET_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe
Then simply doing a system() command with the chrome path "--new-window" and the web path.

Then I let the intermediate html page open it's popup and close itself.

Tada done.

Thanks.